# Python dynamic function parameters

Tags: python, backtrader

When calling the function below, I can provide values that will be used instead of the default parameters in the function (see below).

```
cerebro.addstrategy(GoldenCross, fast=10, slow=25)
```

This works great for a small number of known parameters, but I am moving up to more complex systems. Essentially, I need to pass a fast_1, fast_2, fast_3, etc.... The total amount of these parameters will change (always around 100, but it can vary). Is there a statement that I can write that will dynamically add X amount of parameters to my function call?

I have tried using a for statement in the function call, but I received a syntax error.

Comment: Parameters more than 5 are not always a best coding convention. Give it a model and process inside

Comment: Why does your function have 100 parameters??? If you find yourself passing `x_1, x_2, x_3, ...` then you *really* probably just want to accept a *container* like a `list`

Comment: I agree with the other comments here.  Passing a large number of parameters to a function is very bad form.  Instead of parameters `fast_1`, `fast_2`, etc.. you should pass in `fasts`, a single list parameter containing each of the values you would have otherwise passed as individual `fast_N` parameters.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use of \*args and \*\*kwargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/use-of-args-and-kwargs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood your question of two ways:

1. You want to call your function passing to it different parameters (that are optional), you can accomplish it like this:

```
def add(first, second=0, third=3):
    return (first+second+third)
    
number_list = list(range(1, 200))  # Generates a list of numbers
result = []  # Here will be stored the results


for number in number_list:
    # For every number inside number_list the function add will
    # be called, sending the corresponding number from the list.
    returned_result = add(1,second=number)
    result.insert(int(len(result)), returned_result)

print(result) # Can check the result printing it
```

2. You want your function handles any number of optional parameters, as you don't know any way to determine how many they are, you can send a list or parameters, like this:

```
def add(first,*argv):
    for number in argv:
        first += number
    return first

number_list = (list(range(1, 200)))  # Generates a list of numbers
result = add(1,*number_list)  # Store the result

print(result) # Can check the result printing it
```

[Here](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/args_and_kwargs.html) you can find more information about *args

Answer (score 1):

how about using `*`?
`def addstrategy(GoldenCross, *fast, slow = 25):` can be an example.

```
>>> def foo(a, *b, c = 36):
        print(a, b, c)
>>> foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
1 (2, 3, 4, 5) 36
```

You need to initialize `fast` in this case, however.

Comment: I would suggest that you not promote this solution to the OPs problem, as it is very bad form to pass 100+ parameters this way.

Answer (score -1):

Two ways: Either use a variable number of arguments using `*` on the parameter or treat the parameter as an iterable.

```py
def fun1(positional, optional="value", *args):
  print(args) # args here is a tuple, since by default variable number of args using * will make that parameter a tuple.

def fun2(positional, args, optional="value"):
  print(args) # args here will be dependant on the argument you passed.

fun1("some_value", "value", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5) # args = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
fun2("some_value", [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) # args = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Your first function, using a named argument followed by a variable number of positional arguments, is VERY confusing.  You must always supply the `optional` parameter if you want to supply any `*args` parameters.  The optional default of "value" only works in the case where you provide only a single argument to the function. - in any case, I would suggest that you not promote this solution to the OPs problem, as it is very bad form to pass 100+ parameters this wa.

Comment: The thing is I got used with Python 2.7 where optional parameters should always come before the `*args` and `**kwargs`.

Comment: I getcha.  That doesn't change the fact that the API presented by that function is confusing as heck and, IMO, should be avoided. - The two arguments `optional` and `args` become co-dependent.  You can only use the default value of the `optional` argument if you don't have any other positional parameters to pass.  It would be better in this case to just require the `optional` parameter all the time.  If you are going to often want to call the function with a single parameter, I think it would be better to make that a second function to avoid confusion.